# ObservableList javafx sort descending with Comparator

Tags: javafx, comparator, observablelist

ObservableArrayList.sorted works well with primitive data types but if instead reference datatypes can not work

```
ObservableList<NewClass> observableArrayList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
            observableArrayList.add(new NewClass(1, "name 1"));
            observableArrayList.add(new NewClass(2, "name 2"));
            observableArrayList.add(new NewClass(4, "name 4"));
            observableArrayList.add(new NewClass(5, "name 5"));
            observableArrayList.add(new NewClass(3, "name 3"));

            observableArrayList.sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder());


class NewClass
private int stt
private int name
```

Error message

```
incompatible types: inference variable T has incompatible bounds
    equality constraints: sf.enforcement.NewClass
    upper bounds: java.lang.Comparable<? super T>
```

I want to sort in the stt order of the Newclass, please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Comparator.reverseOrder` only works if there is an order to reverse. This is only the case if `NewClass` implements `Comparable`. Otherwise you need to use a custom comparator:

```
observableArrayList.sort((a, b) -> Integer.compare(b.getStt(), a.getStt()));
```

or

```
Comparator<NewClass> comparator = Comparator.comparingInt(NewClass::getStt);
observableArrayList.sort(comparator.reversed());
```